# How to ingest all the flowfiles in a CRON driven DetectDuplicate?

Tags: cron, duplicates, priority-queue, apache-nifi

In NiFi, I have a cron driven sequence of processors that provides daily a set of flowfiles which contain 2 attributes I am interested in : `product_code` and `publication_date`.

My need is to keep only one flowfile per `product_code`: the one with the most recent `publication_date`.

Ex:

For this input :

```
flow_1: product_code: A / publication_date : 2018-01-01
flow_2: product_code: B / publication_date : 2018-01-01
flow_3: product_code: C / publication_date : 2018-01-01
flow_4: product_code: A / publication_date : 2018-04-12
flow_5: product_code: A / publication_date : 2000-12-31
flow_6: product_code: B / publication_date : 2018-02-02
flow_7: product_code: B / publication_date : 2018-03-03
```

The expected output should be :

```
flow_3: product_code: C / publication_date : 2018-01-01
flow_4: product_code: A / publication_date : 2018-04-12
flow_7: product_code: B / publication_date : 2018-03-03
```

## The algorithm I tested

1. Use an `UpdateAttribute` processor to add an attribute `priority` to each flowfile, based on the `publication_date`.
2. These updated flowfiles are redirected to a `PriorityAttributePrioritizer` queue.
3. The flowfiles stay in this queue because there is only one consuming processor, which is cron driven. By this way, I am sure that the flowfiles in the queue are ordered according to the `publication_date`.
4. Then the CRON trigger the next processor, a `DetectDuplicate` based on the `product_code` attribute. As the flowfiles are processed from the most recent item to the oldest one, I am sure that when a `product_code` is detected as duplicate, it is because the same `product_code` was already OK with a more recent `publication_date`.

## The issue

Sadly, when the cron triggers the `DetectDuplicate` processor, only one message is consumed, and the others stay in the queue.

If I change the "Scheduling strategy" to "Timer driven" with a "Run schedule" of 0, all my flowfiles are consumed and the output is what is expected.

Is there a way to ask my `DetectDuplicate` processor to consume all the messages in the queue when it starts to work (and not only one message)?

Or is there a way to set up a scheduling strategy like "Start to work at 2:00 AM and stop at 4:00 AM" ?

Do you think of better strategies to meet the need ?

Regards,

Val.

---

## Update 1

(2018-04-13) More information, in addition to Bryan Bende's comments.

I know CRON is not the best solution, but I do not know how to improve my algorithm to get rid of it.

In my case, the flowFiles that are queued to be deduplicated are generated via a sequence of 3 REST calls:

- 1st call to "GetAllCategories",
- then for each category, call the "GetSubCategories",
- and for each subCategory, call the "GetProducts".

This flowFiles generation part lasts generally around 5 minutes: last night the first flowFile arrived in the queue at 2:00:16 AM and the last one at 2:04:58 AM. (That's why I scheduled the `DetectDuplicate` to run at 3:00 AM.)

If my `DetectDuplicate` processor would be "Timer driven" scheduled, the first flowFiles arriving in the queue would be consumed by the processor, before all the flowFiles to be there.

And this would break the ordering of the full set of flowFiles.

I feel like I have to wait all the flowfiles to be in the queue before the `DetectDuplicate` processor starts working.

Do you have potential suggestions to improve my algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally use CRON scheduling for the source processor that starts the flow and then all other processors should be Timer Driven with Run Schedule of 0.

For example, if you pick up files from a directory every day at 2:00 AM, then GetFile should be scheduled with a CRON expression to start the flow at 2:00 AM, but nothing beyond that needs CRON scheduling because they will never receive data unless GetFile runs.

In the case where you want a processor to wait to execute until all flow files are available, you may be able to use the Wait/Notify processors, such that all the flow files build up in front of a Wait processor before being released to the DetectDuplicate processor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bryan. I know CRON is not the best solution, but I do not know how to improve my algorithm to get rid of it. I have just updated my question to add comments regarding your answer.

Comment: @ValBonn As far as I know, DetectDuplicate only operates on one flow file at a time. It takes a flow file and uses some identifier to check against a cache of previously seen identifiers, and does this for each flow file one at a time. So I don't think you need to have all the flow files waiting before the processor, you can just schedule GetAllCategories on a CRON, everything else timer.

Comment: You are right @BryanBende when you describe the behavior of DetectDuplicate. But let me clarify the case : 1/ Execution of GetAllCategories. 2/ First getProduct brings back "product: A / publication_date : `2000-01-01`" 3/ This flowFile enters the DetectDuplicate, and as it is the first flowFile for product A, it will pass. 4/ Few seconds later, another getProduct brings back "product: A / publication_date : `2018-04-12`" 5/ This flowFile enters the DetectDuplicate 6/ This flowFile is rejected: it's the same product as step (3). ---  But in my case, it is this latest flowFile I'd need to keep

Comment: I don't really understand how you are trying to use DetectDuplicate... if you are trying to detect duplicate products then what you described sounds like correct behavior. If you want to detect duplicate products within a category, then you need to make the identifier product+category and not just product.

Comment: I do not try to detect duplicates on product+category. I try to implement a "smart" detectDuplicate (=detect duplicates on "prioritized" list). Let's try to simplify. 
My flowFiles have 2 attributes : a `code` and a `date`. I need to keep only one flowFile per `code` : the one with the **most recent date**.  e.g. For these flowFiles IN : {prod_A:2018 Jan 01}, {prod_B: 2018 Jan 01}, {prod_A: 2018 Feb 02}, {prod_A: 1999 Jan 01}, {prod_B: 2018 Feb 01}.  I need these OUT : {prod_A: 2018 Feb 02} and {prod_B: 2018 Feb 01} that are the most recent flowFiles for prod_A and the most recent for prod_B.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I understand what you are trying to do now. I'm honestly not sure of the best way to make this work, you may be able to use the Wait/Notify processors if you can somehow know how many things to wait for.

Comment: Hi @BryanBende. I built a POC to test the Wait/Notify solution you proposed. It was not so easy: I need to use 2 Notify processors and it seems all the flowFiles stay in the queue until the last flowFile is there. Thank you ! I will try to adapt it on my real case tomorrow. 
Do you think you can amend your answer before I validate it ? Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad you got something working, I added a small paragraph to the answer about Wait/Notify.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why only one message gets consumed is when you have the `CRON` scheduling enabled in all the processors - source and consuming/dowstream processors, it executes like this:

**Ex:** You have set up a CRON schedule in all processors to run on every day 2 PM, so during the trigger it will consume one flowfile from its upstream processor ex: `GetFile` at 2PM and the rest of the flowfiles will be on the queue and the next flowfile will only be consumed on the next day at 2PM and so on. And this applies to the further downstream processors, meaning, they will also consume only flowfile at a time at everyday 2 PM which is essentially a disaster in the making. Who wants the processing to be in snail's pace?

That's why you have to follow the approach @Bryan had mentioned. The flow pipeline should only have its source processor as `CRON driven`, the rest of the processors should be `Timer driven` with a run schedule of your wish, but generally `0 sec` is used to consume the flowfile as it comes.

Comment: Thank you Sivaprasanna Sethuraman. I do not have all processors scheduled at 2PM: my (equivalent to) GetFile runs at 2PM, and my DetectDuplicate is scheduled at 3PM. (Typically everything to be deduplicated is available in the queue at 2:05PM). 
And using a timer driven with 0 sec will "consume the flowfile as it comes". But I do not want this behaviour. I need to guarantee the order the flowfiles will be consumed.